# Modifications of shortcut target path?

Tags: vbscript, shortcut

I need to change the shortcut target path from "google.com" to "yahoo.com" using the following VBScript:

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set shortcut = sh.CreateShortcut("C:\Wherever\Shortcut.lnk")
shortcut.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files(x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://www.google.com"
shortcut.Save
```

When I'm running this from CMD

```
cscript file.vbs
```

I'm getting the following error:

> excepted end of statement

Do I need to add `<script language=script>` or anything else?

Comment: Your script worked great for me, even with all the weird spacing.  Please post the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set shortcut = sh.CreateShortcut("C:\temp\Shortcut.lnk")
shortcut.TargetPath = "c:\temp"
shortcut.Save
```

Also, your script worked perfectly as-is after I created `c:\wherever\`.

[image]

Please post your error if it still doesn't work after ensuring the folder exists.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your target path string is incorrect. You need to put double quotes around the entire string, plus you need to put escaped double quotes around the Internet Explorer path inside the string, because that path contains spaces. In VBScript you escape double quotes inside a string by doubling them.

Change this line:

```
shortcut.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files(x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://www.google.com"
```

into this:

```
shortcut.TargetPath = """C:\Program Files(x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"" http://www.google.com"
```

and the error will disappear.